# Return Statement JsonResult inside WcfCall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I return the Json for the ActionResult while using a WCF call?

The below works if I was using EF and a using block for the db call.

But it is showing me the errors I commented out.

```
public JsonResult GetNames(string name)
{
    WcfWebProxy.Using(delegate(IMyWebService client)
    {
        var names = client.GetAllNames().Select(f => new {Text = f.NewNames});
        return Json(names.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //Return Type Is Void
    });
}
//Return Statement Missing
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a closure:

```
public ActionResult GetNames(string name)
{
    ActionResult res = null;

    WcfWebProxy.Using(client =>
    {
        var names = client.GetAllNames().Select(f => new
        {
            Text = f.NewNames
        });
        res = Json(names.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    });

   return res;
}
```

Of course if the `WcfWebProxy.Using` method is asynchronous you should use asynchronous controllers as illustrated in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

And by the way that's definitely something you should consider if you are dealing with I/O intensive operations such as calling WCF services. And with .NET 4.5 and the `async/await` pattern your code might even be readable.